# Multiple local variable vs multiple computation

Tags: java, android, performance

**Which one is more efficient?And is there any better alternative?**

In **first case** I get the file extension ,saves it in a variable,then check if it is mp4 and change to avi if it is mp4.After execution of some lines of code I again need the original extension in a method call so compute it again from the file.

```
String extension = ff.getAbsolutePath().substring(ff.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("."));
 if(extension.equals(".mp4")
extension=".avi"
......
method(ff.getAbsolutePath().substring(ff.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(".")),..,.,)
```

In **second case** I get the file extension ,saves it in a variable,then create another variable and assign it the already computed extension,then check if originalextension is mp4 and then change extension of second variable to avi if it is mp4.After execution of some lines of code I again need the original extension in a method call which i have saved in originalextension variable so I get it from there.

```
String originalextension = ff.getAbsolutePath().substring(ff.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("."));
String extension=originalextension;
 if(originalextension.equals(".mp4")
extension=".avi"
.......
method(originalextension,..,.,)
```

In both cases ,extension and originalextension are local variables.

In first case ,I declared only one local variable but I need to compute file extension two times.In second case I declared two local variables and I need to compute file extension only one time

Comment: Forget efficiency in this case (both runtime and memory impact will be negligible), focus on readability. Since the expression is pretty long, use two local variables. And you might want to try to extract the middle part (for which you need the corrected extension) into another method.

Comment: @MalteHartwig thanks..I don't understand wht u mean by saying "And you might want to try to extract the middle part (for which you need the corrected extension) into another method"

Comment: The fact that you store `originalext`, then "correct" it and only at the end call a method with `originalext` makes me think that the middle part (the extension correction and what you marked with `......`) should be in a separate method. It could lead to more readable code. But I can't say for sure without knowing the complete code, of course.